# Using CursorAdapter when displaying a single item

Tags: android, android-cursor, android-cursorloader

I have a `ListFragment` which displays a list of items obtained using a `CursorLoader` and a `CursorAdapter` as per the standard way of handling views of lists.  This in itself is working fine,however I'm unsure as to how to use the same pattern to display the detailed view of a selected item.

A [previous StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4831330/using-adapters-for-non-list-views) discussed this but neither of the solutions suggested seem to me to be optimal.  Using a `ListView` with a single item seems like overkill and wasteful of resources, whereas carrying out the work directly in the activity seems to be overloading the activity with data access and UI functionality.  It also loses the ability to keep data in sync between the activity and the underlying storage.

Is there some middle ground that retains the split between loader, activity and adapter but for a single item rather than a list?

Comment: Why can't you simply use another loader to retrieve that single's element details?

Comment: whats wrong with DetailedActivity and passing item Uri/id via Intents ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do without the Adapter and the ListView.

The CursorLoader returns you a Cursor. You can access the cursor without passing it to an adapter.
Just make sure the Cursor contains at least your one row.

```
if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
  // do whatever, ie String myString=cursor.getString(0)
  // in case you fetch a string as the first element of your projection  
}
```

Comment: SO if I ditch the adapter but keep the loader will I retain the ability for the data to be refreshed when the underlying datastore changes?

Comment: Correct. The loader will deliver you a new cursor when that happens.

Comment: No need to use a Loader when you want to return just one row, use Cursor.registerContentObserverto do auto refresh